# Change Column number depending on a variable

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have some VBA code that inserts formulae into a series of named Excel cells. The formulae are used to get values from specific sheets in a second workbook (`DoD_Options.xlsm`) with the name of sheet to be used defined by a part of a string variable (`DrawingCode`) which has the structure `DODss.sxww`. The characters to the left of the "x" (DODss.s) define the sheet name to be used (e.g. DOD4.3, DOD8.7 etc) whilst the characters to the right of the "x" (nn) indirectly determine the columns within the sheet where the data is held . The values of `nn` can be any of 7 values (19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49) and correspond to columns L, AP, BT, CX, EB, FF and GJ in the respective sheet.

As an example, when `DrawingCode = DOD2.9x19`, the code

`Range("FS1.0_Count").Formula = "=INDIRECT(""[DoD_Options.xlsm]"" & LEFT(DrawingCode,FIND(""x"",DrawingCode)-1)&""!$L$5"")*Dock_Count"`

inserts the formula to get the value from cell `L5` in sheet `DOD2.9` whilst with `Drawingcode = DOD2.9x24` the code

`Range("FS1.0_Count").Formula = "=INDIRECT(""[DoD_Options.xlsm]"" & LEFT(DrawingCode,FIND(""x"",DrawingCode)-1)&""!$AP$5"")*Dock_Count"`

gets the value from cell `AP5` in sheet `DOD2.9`.

At present I have code that checks for the 7 possible values of `nn` like this:

```
If nn = "19" Then
Range("FS1.0_Count").Formula = "=INDIRECT(""[DoD_Options.xlsm]"" & LEFT(DrawingCode,FIND(""x"",DrawingCode)-1)&""!$L$5"")*Dock_Count"
Range("FV1.04_Count").Formula = "=INDIRECT(""[DoD_Options.xlsm]"" & LEFT(DrawingCode,FIND(""x"",DrawingCode)-1)&""!$L$6"")*Dock_Count"
.... etc for 18 more ranges

ElseIf nn = "24" Then
Range("FS1.0_Count").Formula = "=INDIRECT(""[DoD_Options.xlsm]"" & LEFT(DrawingCode,FIND(""x"",DrawingCode)-1)&""!$AP$5"")*Dock_Count"
Range("FV1.04_Count").Formula = "=INDIRECT(""[DoD_Options.xlsm]"" & LEFT(DrawingCode,FIND(""x"",DrawingCode)-1)&""!$AP$6"")*Dock_Count"
... etc for 18 more ranges

ElseIf nn = 29" Then
...etc
End If
```

Instead of having multiple lines of almost identical code for each value of `nn`, is there a way to condense the coding by using an array to set the column number automatically depending on the value of `nn`?

Answer (score 0):

### Dynamic Columns (`Application.Match`)

- Depending on how you have declared `nn`, you may need to put the values in quotes e.g. "19", "24"...

```vb
Sub matchNN()

    Dim nns As Variant
    nns = Array(19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49)
    Dim cols As Variant
    cols = Array("L", "AP", "BT", "CX", "EB", "FF", "GJ")
 
    Dim cIndex As Variant: cIndex = Application.Match(nn, nns, 0)
    
    If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
        Range("FS1.0_Count").Formula = "=INDIRECT(""[DoD_Options.xlsm]""" _
            & "&LEFT(DrawingCode,FIND(""x"",DrawingCode)-1)&""!$" _
            & cols(cIndex) & "$5"")*Dock_Count"
        Range("FV1.04_Count").Formula = "=INDIRECT(""[DoD_Options.xlsm]""" _
            & "&LEFT(DrawingCode,FIND(""x"",DrawingCode)-1)&""!$" _
            & cols(cIndex) & "$6"")*Dock_Count"
        '... etc for 18 more ranges
    Else
        MsgBox "nn not found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  `nn` is a String so, as you state, coded `nns = Array("19", "24", "29", "34", "39", "44", "49")`.  Also, I had to modify slightly in order to select the correct entry in the `cols` array.  For example, if `nn="19"`, `cIndex = 1` but `cols(cIndex)` produces `AP` and not `L`.  Therefore had to change the coding to `cols(cIndex-1)` (i.e. it appears that the indexing starts at 0 and not 1)